# Amazon AWS - simple email service for Sydney region

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

It seems that the Amazon simple email service is not available for the region - Asia (Sydney). We are using the other services available for the region. We do not want to change the region.

So is is possible to use SES from another region from codes like any SMTP server?

Comment: How are you using SES? Using API or SMTP?

Answer (score 2):

SES is just an authenticated endpoint on the internet. It doesn't matter where you are originating the messages from as long as you can authenticate those messages to SES it will process them.

Obviously you'll get charged cross region / outbound data rates for doing so.

Comment: when we change the region from lets say Asia(Sydney) to US it stops working. Any idea why? And what needs to update?

Comment: Not exactly. But emails are not delivered.

Comment: @Rahat  SES gives reasonably good error codes when it rejects connections. So at  some point you should either be getting an error code or a failure to connect. Its difficult to say any more without that information, but SES doesn't care where messages come from.

Answer (score 0):

It's only available in us-east-1, us-west-2 and eu-west-1 so you'll have to use one of those.

us-west-2 is best from Sydney (ap-southeast-2).

```
>ping email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Minimum = 210ms, Maximum = 211ms, Average = 210ms

>ping email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
Minimum = 160ms, Maximum = 161ms, Average = 160ms

>ping email.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
Minimum = 275ms, Maximum = 276ms, Average = 275ms
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pinpoint ap-southeast-2 to send emails now